# Understanding an oscillator circuit

Tags: oscillator, ultrasound

I'm trying to build a driver circuit for an ultrasonic transducer for fog making. The circuit is required to generate a 1.6 MHz signal to drive the ultrasonic transducer.

I have found a circuit which seems to be working from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rZcX6kO3Tg). The author of the video claims that he designed the circuit. Here is the circuit, ( The buzzer symbol is used for the ultrasonic transducer)

[image: Ultrasonic fogger circuit]

I have built the circuit and it works to some extent. I was able to capture an output waveform using my USB Oscilloscope.
[image]

The circuit generate a good 1.7 MHz sine wave. However, I am unable to understand what type of oscillator is this. It seems to be a Colpitts oscillator, but I cannot find how to match this with a Colpitts oscillator.

I need to understand the operation of the circuit and how to change/calculate frequency values.

**Edit**--

Here is the waveform between base and emitter. It has the same frequency
[image]

Comment: That is just so wrong. Take a look at the waveforms in the emitter and base of Q1, these are probably going above the rail. I believe it is a class C stage of sorts. And the gain is coming from driving Q1 into reverse active region. I guess the RTC generates the input to be able to start the oscillation.

Comment: 4 volts peak to peak seems a low yield from a 32 volts supply. It's not a colpitts and it was probably slung together hit and miss until something worked and then the designer said freeze.

Comment: @Edgar Brown I have added the waveform between base and emitter. Can you kindly explain me what you meant by 'driving Q1 into reverse active region' ?

Comment: @Andy aka Yes it's indeed a low yield having such a low peak to peak voltage. That is an another problem I am trying to solve. Since the amplitude is low, the transducer can 'shake' the water but cannot produce any fog. Also the frequency seems to be wrong. The transducer is rated at 1.6 MHz. I have too suspected that the circuit is not exactly a 'designed' one but made by trial and error. But it seems to be working. That's why I'm interested.

Comment: I would suggest that you post a screen shot of the circuit shown in the video in case you have misinterpreted it. I honestly cannot see this producing a reliable oscillation.

Comment: @Andy aka The schematic is an screenshot from his video ( Another video of him showing the same design) [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XEkeVaJEFQ) I have watched the video carefully, only thing that can be different is the Inductor  since it was made by simply wrapping some wire. The funny thing is the circuit works somehow.

Comment: Also I guess the capacitance of the Ultrasonic transducer has something to do with the oscillation.

Comment: Try making the inductor more like 4.7 uH and see what happens. If it all goes wrong then this underpins the basic problem and, that is: Nobody understands the principle of operation of this oscillator so it's just guesswork and intuition that drives suggestions AND, those suggestions (like mine above in this comment) may be miles-off being correct. This is why people use recognized oscillator types because there is a wealth of knowledge and you can easily tap into it.

Comment: @Andy aka I have already tried with a different inductor, but the results are same. Still I get the 1.7 MHz Oscillation. I guess it's pointless to stick with this circuit anymore. It's some 'mysterious' thing. I wish to build the fogger with an other design. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The frequency should remain the same because it is the piezo that dictates it. I suggested 4.7 uH in order to get more amplitude. But, of course, this may not be possible with an apparently unproven design. Or make the 1.5 nF capacitor smaller (say 390 pF).

Comment: @Andy aka Yes I think the frequency has defined by piezo. I don't wish to continue with this design anymore. Thank you for your concern!